# How to install godaddy ssl certificate on IBM Cloud?

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud

I requested a certificate from godaddy and I received 5 files.

- generated-csr.txt
- generated-private-key.txt
- 5d4965adef6f6ca8.pem
- 5d4965adef6f6ca8.crt
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

And on IBM Cloud SSL configuration board, I have to upload the following:

- Certificate - Allowed file extensions: cert, cer, der, crt, pem, p7b, p7r, spc
- Private Key - Allowed file extensions: key, pem, p8, pk8
- Intermediate certificate (optional) - Allowed file extensions: cert, cer, der, crt, pem, p7b, p7r, spc
- Client certificate trust store (optional) - Allowed file extensions: cert, cer, der, crt, pem, p7b, p7r, spc

I have tried different combinations but I can not get it to work. Even when it says that the upload was succsessful and I save it, when I try to acces my aplication url it says that the certificate is invalid and it shows an IBM certificate and not the godaddy certificate.

[image]

Comment: Where do you upload the SSL certificate? There are a couple components in IBM Cloud where you could do it? Is it IBM Certificate Manager? And for what type of application (which compute option)?

Comment: I uploaded it in: Manage->Account->Cloud Foudry org->Name of my org->Domains->SSL Certificate->Upload.  I'm using it for my frontend, it is a Cloud Foudry Applications made with Angular.

Comment: So is your your app a Cloud Foundry app? Does the route match the domain specification in the certificate?

Comment: Yes! And the rout match the domain specification. But when I try to acces the url in a browser get "invalid certificate". Apparently IBM is showing theier certificate insted of mine.

Comment: Please post more details on how you configured the route